# How do I compare if two object references are the same in Powershell (i.e. Identity/Same operator)?

Tags: powershell

How do I compare if two object references are the same in Powershell?

I'm looking for an operator where

```
$true <op> $true # is true
$true <op> "true" # is false
"true" <op> $true # is false
```

I have eliminated all of the [powershell comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6) and it is not = and not ==.

I thought that `-is` would be the answer because of this erroneous description in the powershell doc linked above:

> Type  -is Returns true if both object are the same

However, it is described accurately further into the documentation:

> The type comparison operators (-is and -isnot) are used to determine
>   if an object is a specific type.

Therefore the following causes an error:

```
$true -is $true
```

Error:

```
[ERROR] Cannot convert value "True" to type "System.Type". Error: "Invalid cast from 'System.Boolean' to 'System.Type'."
[ERROR] At line:1 char:1
[ERROR] + $true -is $true
[ERROR] + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ERROR]     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
[ERROR]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
[ERROR]
```

Comment: `$true.Equals($true)`

Comment: `[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers]::Equals($true, $true)`